# Real background image size in android (with status bar)

Tags: android, background, statusbar

I'd like to use a high detail image as backrgound in my app, and I've got a problem with my designer because of this :-D

By now, we've got three image sizes (one per density) according to the most common devices' screen size, as we know:

- low: 240 x 320 (e. HTC Tattoo)
- mid:320 x 480 (e. HTC Magic)
- high: 480 x 800 (e. Nexus One)

The problem is that, when I set an image as background, it gets resized, and I can see several horizontal "ghost" lines on it.

So we decided to resize the images with "height-minus-statusbar's height" (only in high-density one, just as test), having finally a 480 + 752 px image (according to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html , the status bar's height is 48px)

But it still shows those "ghost" lines, so we think it's being resized again...

Could someone help me? I just want a normal background, with no resizing, but I don't know the real dimensions...

Thank you :-D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are setting yourself up to be in a continual state of pain.  You simply can not design against exact resolutions; there is too much variation in devices for that, and by doing so you are going to be slapped in the face continually as you encounter new devices.  Android has a lot of facilities for dealing with this screen variety, such as 9-patches, its density management, layout managers, etc.  If you take advantage of those, you will be happy; if you don't, you will be swearing all the time.

But if you want to swear, I can't stop you.  Just please don't take to the net complaining about Android fragmentation. :)

As far as your image being scaled due to the status bar -- yes the status bar takes a chunk out of the screen.  How much is not defined, so it could well vary slightly between devices.  The window background, as set by Activity.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(), will extend behind the status bar (and IME or other variable system decoration), so at least using that will reduce the variation.  That said, the actual display space could be carved out for other reasons from the physical screen size; it intentionally isn't defined exactly what part of the screen an app gets to play in.

Comment: I see. I supposed that was going to be the answer... I prefer NinePatches, and I think I'll ask to my designer to make simpler backrgound images. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget about the Droid A855 (480x854 resolution), or the Galaxy Tab (1024x600), or the many other resolutions out there. Your best bet, if you need it pixel-perfect, is to make an image the size of the largest resolution in its category (i.e. 480x854 for a normal sized hdpi screen) and <strike>just set it as an ImageView, with a scaleType of centerCrop.</strike> On second thought, an ImageView would work (if using the android:background attribute) but is unnecessary. You can simply set the NinePatch background as the background attribute of your root layout (e.g. RelativeLayout, LinearLayout). If the NinePatch is correctly formatted, the background will be centered, and the frame will stretch to fit the remaining space without distortion. On a Nexus One, you'd be cutting off the top and bottom 27 pixels of the image, but it would not be resized.

A better suggestion, depending on the type of image it is, would be to make part of it into a NinePatch. For example, if it has a small border or frame on the outer edges, make the primary part of the background smaller (430 x 750?), and make the outer edges of the frame stretch via NinePatch. This way, even if there's a new device with a slightly different resolution, it will still scale to fit properly, without any stretching.

Comment: Thanks! We can't support all resolutions in the first version of the app... but we've got 'em in mind :-D. Making the view an ImageView it's possible, but we need to be set as background, because it will have different TextViews and a ProgressBar overlaying it... and (trying to avoid changing the image), 9nine is not a good solution (it gets ugly when it's streched...) So that's why I'm asking for the real size. But if we have to change the image at the end, I think we'll do it. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome if that helps! But if you're getting an ugly result from an enlarged NinePatch, there's something wrong with either the NinePatch, or the implementation. The point of a NinePatch is that it is scalable to any size without distortion. It's best with Android to just avoid thinking your app will ever have a specific resolution and just work with relative sizing and positioning. One thing that could be causing your NinePatch problem is if you're setting it as an ImageView's src attribute. You'll have to use the background attribute. I'll clarify that in my answer.

Comment: Hi there again :-D The main problem is that the image is not resizeable because of its details... because I've used several ninePatch images before :-D (always as background, that's the only way they work). I think at the end my designer partner will hate me, but I'll ask for new scallable backgrounds . Thanks again :-)

Comment: Hi again. :P You really can use NinePatches outside of just a plain background. If you have an outer frame, you just have to place a dot atop both sides of the content (one for each side of the frame) and do the same for the left edge. When I get home, I can work up an example for you if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking for a solution on the background going behind the statusbar when using the following method: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/window-bg-speed.html
I now have just used an arbitrary space at the top of the bg graphic to compensate for the status bar.

I also noticed banding and I don't think it's because it is being resized again. This article fixed the issue on my Nexus S:
http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2010/06/04/android-color-banding/ (also references the developer.android article linked above)